# How to pass MultipartFile/InputStream into domain logic in a clean way?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, architecture, backend

The part of my use case algorithm that is relevant to the question goes as follows:

1. Check if user exists
2. Check if user can receive file
3. Save file to a temporary storage

My implementation of the third point would be copying `InputStream` contents to a new file on disk. That would happen in the `Server Application` layer. However, it would need to be called from the domain layer, thus requiring `InputStream` to be passed through the domain layer.

While I can persist the file and then pass just some reference to it into the domain logic, I would like to avoid that, because if I am correct, it would result in unnecessary reads and writes.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this :-

### Object for which I am storing or fetching a file :-

```
@Data
public class OrganizationDTO implements IBaseDto {
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Company name should not empty")
    private String companyName;
    private String headerLogo;
    private String footerSign;
}
```

### Controller Configuration:-

```
        @Autowired
    private OrganizationService service;

    @PostMapping(path = "/save", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
            public GenericDataDTO save(@RequestParam(required = true) String entityDTOString
                    , @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] headerLogo
            ) throws Exception {
                OrganizationDTO convDTO = new OrganizationDTO();
                GenericDataDTO genericDataDTO = new GenericDataDTO();
                genericDataDTO.setResponseMessage("Success");
                genericDataDTO.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                try {
                    convDTO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entityDTOString, OrganizationDTO.class);
                    if (null != headerLogo[0]) {
                        convDTO.setHeaderLogo(saveFileToServer(headerLogo[0]));
                    }
                    if (headerLogo.length >= 2 && null != headerLogo[1]) {
                        convDTO.setFooterSign(saveFileToServer(headerLogo[1]));
                    }
                    OrganizationDTO dtoData = service.saveEntity(convDTO);
                    genericDataDTO.setData(dtoData);
                    genericDataDTO.setTotalRecords(1);
                    return genericDataDTO;
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
     genericDataDTO.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY.value()); 
 genericDataDTO.setResponseMessage(HttpStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY.getReasonPhrase());
                    return genericDataDTO;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    genericDataDTO.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED.value());
                    genericDataDTO.setResponseMessage("File not saved");
                    return genericDataDTO;
                }
            }
```

### My GenericDataDTO is Like :-

```
@Data
public class GenericDataDTO {
        private int responseCode;
        private String responseMessage;
        private Object data;
        private List dataList;
        private int totalRecords = 0;

        public static GenericDataDTO getGenericDataDTO(List entityList) {
            GenericDataDTO genericDataDTO = new GenericDataDTO();
            genericDataDTO.setDataList(entityList);
            genericDataDTO.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            if (null == entityList) {
                genericDataDTO.setTotalRecords(0);
            } else {
                genericDataDTO.setTotalRecords(entityList.size());
            }
            genericDataDTO.setResponseMessage("Success");
            return genericDataDTO;
        }
    }
```

### And Global method which stores file at Server or temp Storage :-

```
      public String saveFileToServer(MultipartFile argFile) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "Test";
        if (null != argFile) {
            fileName = (null != argFile.getOriginalFilename())
                    ? argFile.getOriginalFilename().replace("/", "_").trim()
                    : fileName;
        }
        File file = new File("Your_temp_storage_path" + LocalDateTime.now() + "_" + fileName);
        try {
            boolean isCreated = file.createNewFile();
            if (!isCreated) {
                throw new FileNotCreatedException();
            }
            if (null != argFile) {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fout.write(argFile.getBytes());
                fout.close();
            }
            return file.getName();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileNotCreatedException();
        }
    }
```

### And exception is like :-

```
public class FileNotCreatedException extends IOException {
    public FileNotCreatedException() {
        super("File not created");
    }

    public FileNotCreatedException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps 1 and 2 are for authentication and authorization, it should be in a filter or even better: configured in your SecurityConfig. see the useful link if you are not familiar: https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

The step 3 should be the only one actually called at your controller level.

**Edit:**
If I understand correctly, you indeed don't want to pass an inputStream reference, if the file is small, you can parse it as `byte[]` or a `resource` and pass the whole thing to your services, if the file is big, then you will probably have to create a temporary file and pass the path of the file to your services:

Comment: Looks like I wanted to simplify things too much, and created a misunderstanding.

I don't mean "user" in terms of authentication or authorization. In my application, it's more like a (public) identifier for a group of points that users can upload to. Means of security you are referring to are a separate problem.